# How do you use TypeScript's SVG Library?

Tags: svg, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and JavaScript, although not completely new to programming. I wondered if someone could help me with a short piece of TypeScript code showing how you would use TypeScripts SVG library to draw. So, for example, should I use SVGRectangle or SVGRectangleElement and how do I use them?

The only example I can find on the TypeScript site uses D3 but I would like to use the built in SVG library.

Comment: What SVG library? I thought TypeScript was just a language, not any libraries.

Comment: There are several .d.ts files available but not yet for SVG.  Typescript is open source, where there's a need there will be some *somebody* that writes an svg.d.ts.  If not you then keep an eye on the Codeplex project for updates.  Meanwhile use straight JS.

Comment: @HansPassant https://github.com/rbakhshi/svg.js/blob/master/svg.d.ts

Comment: @HansPassant and others: nowadays SVG APIs are covered in `lib.d.ts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, TypeScript doesn't have an SVG library - but you can use native JavaScript SVG or one of the SVG libraries in your TypeScript code.

This opens up the samples and tutorials you will find, as you can search for "JavaScript SVG" rather than "TypeScript" SVG.

I recommend the [MDN SVG Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG) as a starting point.

Comment: OK thanks Sohnee, just out of interest what are the SVG* functions which appear on Intellisense when writing TypeScript?

Comment: By default, TypeScript has a definition for things like the DOM, built-in functions and so on - so it will come from that. I imagine SVG is part of the DOM as it is essentially elements nested within it.

Comment: if you want you can use more specialized SVG libraries like SVG.JS (http://svgjs.com/). I created TypeScript declaration file for it : (https://github.com/rbakhshi/svg.js). i'm using it and it is good enough :D

Comment: @Sohnee how would you create an SVG element with TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeScript definition files of existing JavaScript SVG libraries, like [Raphael](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/raphael) or [svgjs](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/svgjs).

Comment: Don't forget about [Snap SVG](http://snapsvg.io/)! See the [Type Search](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) for JavaScript library type definitions.